# Globally changing screen-resolution in Solaris 11.3 running in VirtualBox?

Tags: x11, virtualbox, solaris

I'm running Solaris 11.3 in VirtualBox, and I'd like to increase my screen resolution while working in X11.

I've tried to install VBox GuestAddition, but despite the installation appearing to be successful, the resolution remains unchanged when I resize Solaris' VBox-window.  I can only guess that the VBox-driver didn't work (It does work for Solaris 11.4).

I've successfully changed the resolution by using the System->Preference->Monitors in the Solaris GUI, but that only work for my privileged (with System Administrator profile) user - my normal user remains with the old resolution and using the Preference-setting is ignored.

I've tried using the View->Virtual Screen 1->Resize to(...) in the VBox-window running Solaris.  It worked when I was logged in as a priviliged user, but greyed out for my normal user after I tried to set a resolution.  The resolution remained the same.

+++

So what I'd like to do, is set a new resolution for X11 globally, so all my users gets a higher resolution.  So where/how do I set screen-resolution for X11 on Solaris 11.3 ?

PS: Also, if anybody know why the GuestAddition doesn't work, that would be helpfull too...